# Apache ant не распознает tasks "if"

Tags: ant

Я получаю следующую ошибку при сборке проекта на ant

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.535]
(c) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corporation), 2019. Все права защищены.

D:\ForJob\source-archive\apertum-qsystem>D:\ForJob\apache-ant-1.9.14-bin\apache-ant-1.9.14\bin\ant.bat
Buildfile: D:\ForJob\source-archive\apertum-qsystem\build.xml

-pre-init:

-init-private:

-pre-init-libraries:

-init-private-libraries:

-init-libraries:

-init-user:

-init-project:

-init-macrodef-property:

-check-ivy:

-ivy-define:

-ant-contrib-define:
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties. It could not be found.

-lib-path-init:

**BUILD FAILED
D:\ForJob\source-archive\apertum-qsystem\nbproject\ivy-impl.xml:40: Problem: failed to create task or type if**
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any / declarations have taken place.

Total time: 0 seconds

D:\ForJob\source-archive\apertum-qsystem>

Answer (score 0):

```
это мой ivy-impl.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 *  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 *  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 *  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 *  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 *  limitations under the License.
 *
-->
<project xmlns:ivy="antlib:fr.jayasoft.ivy.ant" basedir=".." default="default" name="ivy-impl">
    <target name="-check-ivy">
        <available property="have.ivy" resource="fr/jayasoft/ivy/ant/antlib.xml"/>
    </target>
    <target depends="-check-ivy" name="-ivy-define" unless="have.ivy">
        <echo level="debug" message="ivy.home : ${ivy.home}"/>
        <taskdef resource="fr/jayasoft/ivy/ant/antlib.xml" uri="antlib:fr.jayasoft.ivy.ant">
            <classpath>
                <fileset dir="${ivy.home}">
                    <include name="*.jar"/>
                </fileset>
            </classpath>
        </taskdef>
    </target>
    <target name="-ant-contrib-define">
        <echo level="debug" message="ant-contrib.lib: ${ant-contrib.lib}"/>
        <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties">
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="${ant-contrib.lib}"/>
            </classpath>
        </taskdef>
    </target>
    <target name="-lib-path-init">
        <echo level="debug" message="$${lib.dir} : ${lib.dir}"/>
        <if>
            <equals arg1="${lib.dir}" arg2="$${lib.dir}"/>
            <then>
                <if>
                    <equals arg1="${build.classes.dir}" arg2="$${build.classes.dir}"/>
                    <then>
                        <property name="lib.dir" value="lib"/>
                    </then>
                    <else>
                        <property name="lib.dir" value="jar"/>
                    </else>
                </if>
            </then>
        </if>
        <echo level="debug" message="$${lib.dir} : ${lib.dir}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${basedir}/${build.dir}/${lib.dir}"/>
    </target>
    <target depends="-ivy-define, -ant-contrib-define, -lib-path-init" name="-ivy-retrieve">
        <ivy:settings file="ivysettings.xml"/>
        <ivy:resolve file="ivy.xml"/>
        <ivy:retrieve pattern="${basedir}/${build.dir}/${lib.dir}/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" type="jar"/>
        <path id="ivy.path">
            <fileset dir="${basedir}/${build.dir}/${lib.dir}">
                <include name="**/*.jar"/>
            </fileset>
        </path>
        <pathconvert dirsep="/" pathsep="${path.separator}" property="ivy.classpath.computed">
            <path refid="ivy.path"/>
            <!--map from="${basedir}${file.separator}" to=""/-->
        </pathconvert>
        <property name="old.javac.classpath" value="${javac.classpath}"/>
        <var name="javac.classpath" unset="true"/>
        <if>
            <equals arg1="${old.javac.classpath}" arg2=""/>
            <then>
                <property name="javac.classpath" value="${ivy.classpath.computed}"/>
            </then>
            <else>
                <property name="javac.classpath" value="${old.javac.classpath}${path.separator}${ivy.classpath.computed}"/>
            </else>
        </if>
        <echo level="debug" message="$${javac.classpath} : ${javac.classpath}"/>
        <property name="old.javac.test.classpath" value="${javac.test.classpath}"/>
        <var name="javac.test.classpath" unset="true"/>
        <if>
            <equals arg1="${old.javac.test.classpath}" arg2=""/>
            <then>
                <property name="javac.test.classpath" value="${ivy.classpath.computed}"/>
            </then>
            <else>
                <property name="javac.test.classpath" value="${old.javac.test.classpath}${path.separator}${ivy.classpath.computed}"/>
            </else>
        </if>
        <echo level="debug" message="$${javac.test.classpath} : ${javac.test.classpath}"/>
        <property name="old.run.classpath" value="${run.classpath}"/>
        <var name="run.classpath" unset="true"/>
        <if>
            <equals arg1="${old.run.classpath}" arg2="$${run.classpath}"/>
            <then>
                <property name="run.classpath" value="${ivy.classpath.computed}"/>
            </then>
            <else>
                <property name="run.classpath" value="${old.run.classpath}${path.separator}${ivy.classpath.computed}"/>
            </else>
        </if>
        <echo level="debug" message="$${run.classpath} : ${run.classpath}"/>
        <property name="old.run.test.classpath" value="${run.test.classpath}"/>
        <var name="run.test.classpath" unset="true"/>
        <if>
            <equals arg1="${old.run.test.classpath}" arg2="$${run.test.classpath}"/>
            <then>
                <property name="run.test.classpath" value="${ivy.classpath.computed}"/>
            </then>
            <else>
                <property name="run.test.classpath" value="${old.run.test.classpath}${path.separator}${ivy.classpath.computed}"/>
            </else>
        </if>
        <echo level="debug" message="$${run.test.classpath} : ${run.test.classpath}"/>
        <property name="old.debug.classpath" value="${debug.classpath}"/>
        <var name="debug.classpath" unset="true"/>
        <if>
            <equals arg1="${old.debug.classpath}" arg2="$${debug.classpath}"/>
            <then>
                <property name="debug.classpath" value="${ivy.classpath.computed}"/>
            </then>
            <else>
                <property name="debug.classpath" value="${old.debug.classpath}${path.separator}${ivy.classpath.computed}"/>
            </else>
        </if>
        <echo level="debug" message="$${debug.classpath} : ${debug.classpath}"/>
    </target>
    <target name="-ivy-publish">
        <ivy:settings file="ivysettings.xml"/>
        <ivy:resolve file="ivy.xml"/>
        <ivy:publish forcedeliver="true" overwrite="true" resolver="local">
            <artifacts pattern="${basedir}/${dist.dir}/[artifact].[ext]"/>
        </ivy:publish>
    </target>
    <target name="-ivy-clean">
        <!--delete dir="lib"/-->
    </target>
</project>
```